# Number of rows considered by a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to find out how many rows are considered by a query without performing a count(*) on the source?

example:

```
 Create table test (col1 int , col2 int)

  Insert into test select 1,2 union select 2,3

  Select avg(col1) from test
```

If I use @@rowsaffected it returns the number of rows returned by the query which is 1. But I would like to find out the number of rows considered by the query.

(In my original case the source is a view that contains many tables.)

Comment: That's exactly what `COUNT()` is used for. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: using a count on my source takes 16 minutes. So I would really love to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AVG(col1),
       COUNT(*),/*Number of rows*/
       COUNT(col1), /*Number of non null rows that were used in the Avg*/
       SUM(1) /*Avoids use of COUNT!*/
FROM   test
```

Regarding the comment about `COUNT` taking a long time it should add precisely no additional work to your `AVG` query. If you try

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
GO

SELECT AVG(high)
FROM master..spt_values

GO

SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT OFF
```

It returns

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=CASE WHEN [Expr1004]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1005]/CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1004],0) END))
       |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=COUNT_BIG([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[high]), [Expr1005]=SUM([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[high])))
            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[spt_valuesclust]))
```

You will see it already uses `COUNT` (or `COUNT_BIG` actually) in order to return `NULL` if there were zero matching rows.

Comment: If I use a count on the source it takes 16 more minutes and I would really love to avoid it.

Comment: @Corovei - I just noticed on this version of the comment you say 16 **more** minutes. That definitely doesn't sound right. You weren't doing `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` or `COUNT(some_other_column)`? If this is reproducible please add the execution plan into your question.

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei - Is the expression you are `COUNT`-ing expensive to compute? [Just came across this article and remembered this question](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/27/bug-slow-sums-and-averages.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's do some simulations and see if it actually should take 16 minutes for count(*).

Testing the query:

```
 select count(*) cnt, avg (price) avg from MY_TABLE
```

where MY_TABLE has over 1,500,000 records, the above query takes 1m24sec and only 1sec for consequent runs, so you either have many more records or there is something else going on.

FURTHER TESTS:

running select avg (price) avg from MY_TABLE takes: 1m25sec

running select count(*) cnt from MY_TABLE takes: 4sec

SQL Server was restarted between tests.

Tested on a DELL Vostro 1500 with 2GB RAM and 2.2 GHz CORE 2 Duo and Windows 7 32 but, SQL Server 2000.

Comment: running select avg (price) avg from MY_TABLE takes: 1m25sec, running select count(*) cnt from MY_TABLE takes: 4sec, sql server was restated between test

Comment: my view contains 1.000.000.000 ( 1 billion records )

Comment: @Corovei - Is your query calculating `count(*)` or `count(col1)`? Also is `col1` nullable?